# How can I make a script autostart in a virtual environment in Raspbian?

Tags: linux, virtualenv, raspbian, autostart

The script is a Python script and works in a virtual environment.
Made a shell script "launch.sh" that looks like this:

```
cd /home/pi/test_iot
. bin/activate
python3 rtl433_to_mqtt.py
```

If I run this from the console it works but not from cron.
Running "sudo crontab -e" and then added this line:
`@reboot sh /home/pi/launch.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1`

I get this error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test_iot/rtl433_to_mqtt.py", line 120, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/test_iot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/test_iot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/pi/test_iot/lib/python3.11/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have no clue what's happening here so I hope someone here can see what's wrong.

Comment: So, when you run it interactively - do you run it as `root` or as `pi`?

Comment: When I run interactively I run as pi.

Comment: Have you tried to put `sleep 60` before runing python script ?

Comment: Sleep 60! Think that made it! Hope so but I'll try "tink":s solution a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell by the information provided. My guess is that the cron-job is firing before any network facilities are available. Instead of using `@reboot` from cron, try a systemd service running after `networking` is available.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, I tried "sleep 60 seconds" and that tells me that it is a kind of race condition so I believe this is the best solution so I will try that a bit later,

Comment: @larand - let us know how you get on.

Comment: I'll do I promise in a couple of days or so.

Comment: I just tried to start the script, at boot, as a service and it was successful.

Comment: Pleased to hear that. @larand

Answer (score 0):

Both advices I got here worked perfect but I finally decided to use the service-version as I suspect it is more safe than waiting 60 seconds.

The service defined as:

```
[Unit]
Description=Temperature monitoring through RTL-SDR reciever
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/home/pi/launch.sh
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The running script:

```
enter code here
#!bin/bash
cd /home/pi/test_iot
. bin/activate
#sleep 60# Not needed as we run it as a service that delays start until network online. When run as a cron-job it is needed
python3 rtl433_to_mqtt.py
```